# Column resizing in wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, resize

I am currently developing a WPF software. I am using WPF and am trying to allow the columns to auto size to fit in with the datagrid.

I have used columnwidth="*" which works fine as long as the window is not enclosed within scrollview. If it is in a scroll view then the columns resize really big which causes the datagrid to resize wider off the edge of the screen causing a large amount of scrolling.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3):

You might try binding your scrollviewer's `Width` to the `ActualWidth` of the `DataGrid`. So on the `ScrollViewer` put this (assuming your grid is named MyMainGrid):

```
Width="{Binding ElementName=MyMainGrid, Path=ActualWidth}"
```