# DataGrid with Star column resizes entire DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid with two columns; I want the second column to auto-fit the grid, so I set its width to "*". However, at run-time, the DataGrid resizes to a ridiculous width.

Here's my basic markup with (I think) extraneous controls and attributes removed:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel>
                <DataGrid Name="MyGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                          CanUserResizeColumns="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 1" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Field1}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 2" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Field2}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

I suspect the problem lies with the DataGrid being in the ScrollViewer. I tried setting the ScrollViewer's width to the DataGrid width:

```
Width="{Bidning ElementName=MyGrid, Path=ActualWidth}"
```

as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923966/column-resizing-in-wpf-datagrid), but no luck. I also tried setting HorizontalScrollBarVisibility to Disabled, but then everything disappears (seriously).

I should also mention all of this is in a UserControl which lies in another UserControl which then sits in the Window, which probably has something to do with everything "disappearing" (I suspect widths have gone crazy and everything is 'off the window').

Comment: Are you using .Net 4.0?  I recall another thread on here about 2-3 weeks ago on the same topic.  I think it was determined to be a bug with 4.0 where it worked in 3.5.

Comment: Yes, using .NET 4.0. If this is a duplicate, I'd appreciate if anyone could point me to the previous question.

Comment: I looked for it and couldn't find it. Look under the WPF tag and go back a ways and you might find it.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing everything before the DataGrid, simplifying the layout. The DataGrid already contains a ScrollViewer embedded in its default Template. Plus, using the StackPanel you're allowing its children to fill in all the available space - the StackPanel stretches accordingly to the size of its content. Thus, your `DataGrid` stretches to infinity.

I've also altered the Name property of the DataGrid to the x:Name, and here's why: 
[In WPF, what are the differences between the x:Name and Name attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes)

```
<DataGrid 
    x:Name="MyGrid" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    CanUserAddRows="False" 
    CanUserReorderColumns="False"
    CanUserResizeColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 1" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Field1}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 2" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Field2}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```